# Bootstrap appears in page that shouldn't - asp.net mvc

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, layout

My layout page calls a side menu and also my main page. I want to implement bootstrap in my main page but to exclude from the side menu. I have added the bootstrap call only on my `index.cshtml` file like below:

```
@model MDM.Modules.Monitoring.Web.Models.CacEditViewModel
@using MDM.Modules.Monitoring.Web.Helpers

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CAC";
}

<link href="../../Content/css/modal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../Content/css/popover.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@Html.Action("Header", "Layout")

<h2>
    CAC decisions encoding
</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>General</legend>
    <div class="field">
...
```

And I excluded it from the `_layout.cshtml` file which has the ClientSidebar call like below:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1><img alt="Alter Domus" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/logo.png")"/></h1>
            @Html.Action("MainMenu", "Navigation")
            <span id="welcomeMenu">@User.Identity.Name</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </header>
        <div id="main">
            <aside id="sidebar">
                @Html.Action("ClientSidebar", "Navigation", new { cId = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] })
            </aside>
            <div id="content">
                <section id="contentPlaceHolder">
                    @RenderBody()
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="backLeftLogo">
        </div>
    </div>
```

But my ClientSide bar its still messed up because of bootstrap. I know I can override bootstrap but I need to recreate the whole ClientSideBar when its already created. Any ideas to just exclude the ClientSideBar  from bootstrap?